# Product of finite order elements in a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. Let $a,b\in G$ be of finite order.

Prove or disprove:

(1) If $ab$ has finite order, then $ba$ has finite order.

(2) If $ab$ has finite order, then $a^{-1}b^{-1}$ has finite order.

I do not see both (1) and (2) has to be true. However, I could not give a counter example. I would guess the counterexample must be some kind of non-abelian group.

Comment: Hint:  If you write out $(ba)^k$ and then ignore the first and last letters, what do you see?

Comment: I see it. So both (2) and (1) are true as $(ba)^n=baba...ba=b(abab...ab)a=b(ab)^{n-1}a$ and similarly for $a^{-1}b^{-1}$'s case. But what is the intuition that it has to be true?

Comment: Consider $f : G \rightarrow G$ given by $f(x) = a^{-1} x a$. Notice that $f$ is an isomorphism and $f(ab) = ba$. Hence $ab$ and $ba$ must have the same order (since isomorphisms preserve order).

Comment: @user45765:  I think Pedro's answer provides something which seems very intuitive (at least to me).  I'm not sure how one would first approach the question with intuition...  Also, you (or Pedro) may want to write up an answer (in detail), and post it, so that this question will be officially answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

1) In a group conjugate elements have the same order, i.e. if $\;G\;$ is a group, then

$$ord(x)=ord(x^g)\;,\;\;\forall\,x,g\in G\;,\;\;\text{with}\;\;x^g:=g^{-1}xg$$

2) We have that

$$\forall\,x,y\in G\;,\;\;\;xy=(yx)^y=y^{-1}\left(yx\right)y$$

Answer (score 0):

@Timbuc, you still have to prove (2) of the original OP. To this end we note that ord($a$)=ord($a^{-1}$), that is, the order of an inverse of an element is the same as the order of the element in question. Since $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$, one can now apply (1).